# Flutter export pdf from JSON

Tags: flutter, dart

My data from JSON gives an error when fetching, and it does not display when exported to pdf, any suggestions how to fix this? Thank you.

```dart
class User {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String position;
 
  User(
      {this.id,
      this.name, 
      this.position,
      });

  factory User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => User(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        position: json["position"],
      );
}

class PdfApi {
  static Future<File> generateTable() async {
    var url = Uri.parse('https:....');
    var response = await http.get(url);
    final jsonData = json.decode(response.body);

    final pdf = Document();
    final headers = [
      'id',
      'name',
      'position',
    ];
 
    final data = jsonData.map<User>((json) => User.fromMap(json)).toList();
  }
}
```